# How to manage global textScaleFactor in Flutter app properly?

Tags: flutter, dart, font-size

Flutter apps react on system large text making all Text widgets really large.
I want to limit textScaleFactor for Text widgets but I want to do it globally not in each Text widget that I'am using.

Now after enabling large text I got exceptions like

> flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ flutter:
>   The following message was thrown during layout: flutter: A RenderFlex
>   overflowed by 14 pixels on the bottom.

What is proper way to do it? 
One way is to create some wrapper widget instead of using Text, but maybe it can be solved other way?

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This solution was presented during [Google I/O'19](https://youtu.be/YSULAJf6R6M?t=1277) (around the 20-minute mark):

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor * (_isPassive ? 2 : 1)
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
```

If you wish that everything had a fixed `textScaleFactor`, you could replace `data.textScaleFactor * (_isPassive ? 2 : 1)` for a single number. `1.0` would make your design to always follow your `fontSize`s.

Comment: _isPassive -  what do they store in this variable?

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=YSULAJf6R6M 20:00 they talk about passive way of interacting with content (ex: TV)

Comment: Is there a method to set this globally for all pages?
As far as I can see this method ensures the textScaleFactor only for the widget tree of that screen/page.

Answer (score 8):

You can set a limit after which you don't need to scale, as some apple apps do.

```cpp
MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor > 2.0 ? 2.0 : data.textScaleFactor),
        child: child,
       );
    },
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Flutter app',
)
```

**In addition, I added 2 functions that calculate the size for different cases.**

1. Always returns a fixed text size, for any textScaleFactor:

```cpp
double getFixedSize(double textSize) {
  return textScaleFactor != 1.0 ? textSize / textScaleFactor : textSize;
}
```

*For example, you can use it for app title text.*

2. Returns scaled textSize until specific scale is not reached, which is set by the second maxScaleFactor parameter:

```cpp
double getScaledOrMaxSize(double textSize, double maxScaleFactor) {
 return textScaleFactor > maxScaleFactor
   ? textSize * maxScaleFactor / textScaleFactor
   : textSize;
}
```

*This can be used for example for headers that are already large and you don't need to increase them even more.*

I hope this helps you make good apps for visually impaired people while still leaving them beautiful.

Comment: "as some apple apps do". Could you let me know which apple apps do not scale past a certain threshold?

Comment: You can open standard iPhone apps and continue to scale the font in the iPhone settings, comparing it with the app on flutter, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

To limit the textScaleFactor for **ALL PAGES** in your app, you can do this.

Wrap your `MaterialApp` with a `MediaQuery` widget with the desired `MediaQueryData` data which is created from the `window`.

And set `useInheritedMediaQuery` to `true`.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MediaQueryData windowData =
      MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window);
  windowData = windowData.copyWith(
    textScaleFactor:
        windowData.textScaleFactor > 1.4 ? 1.4 : windowData.textScaleFactor,
  );
  return MediaQuery(
    data: windowData,
    child: MaterialApp(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,

      //...
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Just want to note to be careful setting useInheritedMediaQuery to true. In our app it caused problems in determining the height of the screen when the keyboard is shown.

Comment: @HillelCoren I want to thank you for your comment so very much. I have been banging my head against the wall for weeks as to why every solution online telling me to use singlechildscrollview on login screen and it wasnt working. Soon as I removed that useInheritedMediaQuery all my text menus starting working. :D

Answer (score 0):

Answers have become outdated because `MediaQueryData.fromWindow` is deprecated.  In addition, `MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),` is not always desirable because it forces rebuilds frequently, for instance when a keyboard is displayed.

This solution solves both the deprecation and rebuild issues:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MediaQueryData windowData = MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context));
  windowData = windowData.copyWith(
    textScaleFactor: 1.0, //or whatever you want
  );
  return MediaQuery(
    data: windowData,
    child: MaterialApp(
      //...
    ),
  );
}
```